# Django template : Avoid displaying primary key in html identifiers

Tags: html, ajax, django, tags, identifier

It might seem a stupid question but I have a button which send an AJAX call taking the identifier of the current element like :

```
<div id='myObjectInDB_1234'>
    <input type='text' placeholder = 'New value'/>
    <button class='add_information'>+</button>
</div>
```

And then I link an ajax call to the button. The thing is that I have to send the primary key of the item in order to know who's the target of the modification.

Talking about 'best practices' what's the most efficient way to give this identifier without exposing it publically ? I've seen a lot of website who are doing as above (giving the primary key in an identifier) and I think that this isn't very 'clean'.

Is there any solution ? (We're not talking about hashing the key or HTTPS, it's a simple admin interface)

Thanks !

Comment: One of the way could be to use UUID instead which are not easy to guess. But may not be as efficient as integer primary key as id.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for ! 
And it can be generated in Python in just an instruction, thanks !

Comment: You can use slug field instead of using id.